# Special formatting and/or special characters in text boxes

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible to create a form with a text box that allows the user to change formatting (i.e. bold, italic, underline, etc) or to insert special characters (i.e. Greek letters)?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Although we do not currently have a field that a user can change the formatting in this is a feature that we have added to our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/8KGMkkWb).